# Prevent the loss of data when we change page using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I want to prevent the loss of data when we change page using J QUERY.  I creating a website using MVC. I used a edit button at the top of the page, when I click on that button then its text changes as start editing using j query. But when I change the the page then it loses the start editing text but I want to preserve that text.
I used the following code:

```
function toggleEditor() {
        if (isEditingEnabled) {
            $("[id*=Widget]").each(function () {

                var element = $(this);
                disableEditing(element);
                element.attr('contenteditable', false);
                toggle.innerHTML = 'Start editing';
            });
            isEditingEnabled = false;
            $(".EditableImage").find("a[data-toggle='modal']").remove();
            $("div[id*='Slider']").find("a[data-toggle='modal']").css("display", "none")

            $("#hd_Start").val('Finish editing');
        }
        else {
            $("[id*=Widget]").each(function () {
                var element = $(this);
                element.attr('contenteditable', true);
                enableEditing(element);
                toggle.innerHTML = 'Finish editing';
            });

            $(".EditableImage").append("<a data-toggle='modal' onclick='getSingleImage(this)' href='#modal-form-company-contact1'><div class='edit-indicator-widget' style='top:0;width: 10px;position: absolute;height: 10px;right:45px'><img title='Edit'  src='http://localhost:2442/Content/Content/Images/Edit.png' style='height: 30px;width: 30px;margin:5px;'></div></a>");
            isEditingEnable = true;
            $("div[id*='Slider']").find("a[data-toggle='modal']").css("display", "block")
            $("#hd_Start").val('Start editing');

        }

        //     localStorage.setItem('isEditingEnabled', isEditingEnable);

    }
}
```

Comment: What is your question? I can see you attempted to use local storage, what issues did you encounter?

Comment: Basically i want to preserve the values of a page like when i click on a button named edit then it append some html but when i go to the another page then its can't preserve that html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i got the solution of that problem 
i use localStorage.getItem() method for that purpose.